# What happens when you call a method in a thread that is already working?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, while-loop

Running my test code below it appears that calling a threads method while it is still executing runs the method between the threads current execution.
What I'm wondering is what is exactly happening?

Does the thread pause the while loop, execute the method, and then go back to the loop? Does it do so at the end of the while code or anywhere in between?

Or does the method execute in another separate thread? Or something else altogether?

```
package test;

public class main {
    public static threed thred = new threed();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        thred.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("doing it");
            thred.other();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            thred.x++;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
package test;

public class threed extends Thread {
    public int x;

    public threed() {
        x = 0;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (x < 10) {
            System.out.println(x);          
        }   
    }

    public void other() {
        System.out.println("other " + x);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not calling "the thread's method", it's calling the object's method. It calls them in the main thread, while the thread's `run()` method is running in another thread.

Comment: There is nothing special as such about `Thread` objects except they know how to start a new thread in the JVM.  Methods can be called whenever you have an object in your hand.  The magic happens in the JVM scheduler.

Comment: the method will be executed by both threads independently (eventually in parallel if enough CPUs/cores are present/available)

Comment: As a side note, never expose public mutable object variables. And next perhaps read about `volatile` and `synchronized`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All methods called are using the current thread for all objects.  If you call a method on `Thread` it also calls that method like any other on the current thread.

The only one which is slightly confusion is that `start()` starts another thread and calls `run()` for that new thread.

This is one of the reasons it is best not to extend `Thread` but pass a `Runnable` to it as too often the methods either don't do what they appear to or you get side effects you don't expect.

NOTE: Java often has a proxy object on the heap for managing a resources which is actually off heap (native).  E.g. direct ByteBuffer or JTable or Socket or FileOutputStream.  These objects are not the actual resource as the OS understands them, but an object Java uses to make it easier to manage/manipulate the resource from Java code.

Comment: Are you following me?! This is the third time in the last few days you've beaten me to the same answer by a few seconds :-) (+1 of course though.)

Comment: @MichaelBerry I often hit refresh to see the latest questions which I think means I might see questions sooner.  I should answer questions which have been on for a few minutes... ;)

Comment: IMO, a lot of newbies do not understand the difference between a _thread_, and a `Thread` object. It might help to explain that `start()` is the `Thread` method that _creates_ the actual thread and, that other `Thread` methods are meant for managing that thread.

Comment: @jameslarge I have added a note at the end. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

What happens: the **main** thread does all of this:

```
thred.start(); // start another thread
Thread.sleep(10000); // sleep
while (true) {
   System.out.println("doing it"); 
   thred.other(); // invoke a method on some object
```

Meaning: the **other** thread runs its `run()` method, **nothing** else.

In your code, your **main** thread simply invokes another method on that thread object. It is still happening on the **main** thread!